# How to display a single value for an object in an array instead of the entire object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, template-literals

I'm getting data from an API to be used to display game genres on screen. The issue is the way the code is currently written displays the entire object, but I only want specific values.

```
    const onGameSelect = game => {
    
      
       document.querySelector("#summary").innerHTML = `
       <article class="media">
         <figure class="media-left">
          <p class="image">
           <img src="${game.background_image}" />
           </p>
           </figure>
            <div class="media-content">
              <div class="content">
                <h1>${game.name}</h1>
                <h4>${JSON.stringify(game.genres)}</h4>
                </div>
    
           </article>
           `    
                
    };
```

Result:

```
[
   {
      "id":4,
      "name":"Action",
      "slug":"action"
   },
   {
      "id":11,
      "name":"Arcade",
      "slug":"arcade"
   },
   {
      "id":14,
      "name":"Simulation",
      "slug":"simulation"
   },
   {
      "id":51,
      "name":"Indie",
      "slug":"indie"
   },
   {
      "id":59,
      "name":"Massively Multiplayer",
      "slug":"massively-multiplayer"
   }
]
```

What i want it to display on screen instead:

```
Action
Arcade
Simulation
Indie
Massively Multiplayer
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(game.genres.map(genre => genre.name))`

Comment: something like `game.genres.map(o=>o.name).join(" ")`?

Answer (score 1):

You can just [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it out: `obj.genres.map(o => o.name).join(" ")`

```js
let obj = {genres: [{"id":4,"name":"Action","slug":"action"},{"id":11,"name":"Arcade","slug":"arcade"},{"id":14,"name":"Simulation","slug":"simulation"},{"id":51,"name":"Indie","slug":"indie"},{"id":59,"name":"Massively Multiplayer","slug":"massively-multiplayer"}]};
let genres = obj.genres.map(o => o.name).join(" ")
console.log(genres)

// or

document.querySelector("#summary").innerHTML = `${obj.genres.map(o => o.name).join(" ")}`;
```

```html
<div id="summary"></div>
```

Comment: thank you ! Where did you find how to do this?

Comment: This site actually. When I started trying to answer easy questions, I learned alot about how to update my old methods with newer ways. The link in my answer is the absolute best source of javascript info. It's now something I refer to quite often.